# Angular 12 : router-outlet is not rendering the component after upgrade to dymamic import of router module

Tags: javascript, html, angular, routes, lazy-loading

I have changed my router import from old way of importing

```
loadChildren: './lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule
```

I have used dynamic import to load the router module.

```
loadChildren: () => import('./lazy/lazy.module').then(m => m.LazyModule)
```

Now, my   is not rendering the components but at the same time header and footer, component are loading fine since it is not loaded from the router-outlet.

**app.component.html**

```
<header-component>.  //rendering fine
<router-outlet></router-outlet>. // I am seeing it gets routed in the address bar, but the component is not getting rendering.
<footer-component> //rendering fine
```

I don't get any error on the console or vscode for the above issue.
How do I debug this issue while the components are blank though it is routed correctly also I am getting an API response for this component in the network tab the API response is not get rendered on the screen as HTML.

This issue happened to me while I am upgrading from Angular 11 to the 12 version.

My detailed code structure is pretty same like this document https://remotestack.io/angular-lazy-load-modules-with-dynamic-module-imports-example/

Comment: Have you added the DashboardRoutingModule in imports section at DashboardModule?

Answer (score 0):

@JSBeginner please share your LazyModule code, and it seems you need to specify how you configured routes in the LazyModule module

for example

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LazyComponent],
  },
];
```

and add this line of code on imports of lazyModule

```
RouterModule.forChild(routes),
```

Comment: I have done all these steps but my problem is that my component is not get rendered in the UI and it shows blank body section. i see the routing happening in the browser address bar and getting API response on the network tab and it is not getting rendered